# How to make serial communication from python Dash server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot data received from com port with pyserial using Dash framework. This framework requires web-server to run. When I establish serial communication without dash, just using regular python it works fine, but when I try to use Dash, which starts web-server and (I guess) runs code from there I get SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5).

For Dash framework I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37Zj955LFT0&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfsGImWNt1eUEveHOepkjqt&index=4

I am new to Dash and python in general, so I would appreciate any tip on how to make this work

Comment: [sudo](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/68579288/just-sudo-it.jpg). This is usually caused by insufficient permissions

Comment: yes, I (kind of) understand that web-server created by Dash has no permission to use serial port, but what can I do? If it helps I work on windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and turning off debug mode solved it for me:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

However, when debug mode was off, the app was reloading upon starting and trying to open the serial port again (when it had already been opened). So I changed `use_reloader` to `False`, and it turns out you can keep it in debug mode (or not) like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I'm not sure how some of the [official examples](https://github.com/plotly/dash-daq-sparki/blob/master/app.py) work without disabling reloading but they have other code after the import statements:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
```

and a previous commit removed the following line after the preceding two:

```
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
```

So that *might* take care of it in situations when you need reloading (not sure what reloading does anyway), but I haven't tested it enough to understand.